# What causes the forward word motion to have a delay when "mapleader" is set to space?

Tags: cursor-motions

With the following `mapleader` I have a one second delay when performing a forward word motion (`w` in normal mode). Is there any way to prevent this?

```vim
let mapleader = "\<Space>"
```

Comment: I don't see how the two would be connected. Could you try again, with `$ vim --clean` and `$ vim -Nu NONE`?

Comment: Thank you @romainl - I thought it was unusual. I found the offending plugin in a system package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a system-wide package I had installed on Arch Linux called `vim-align`. The culpable file:

`/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/AlignMapsPlugin.vim`